# Use Kafka Connect to update Elasticsearch field on existing document instead of creating new

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have Kafka set-up running with the Elasticsearch connector and I am successfully indexing new documents into an ES index based on the incoming messages on a particular topic.

However, based on incoming messages on another topic, I need to append data to a field on a specific document in the same index.

Psuedo-schema below:

```
{
   "_id": "6993e0a6-271b-45ef-8cf5-1c0d0f683acc",
   "uuid": "6993e0a6-271b-45ef-8cf5-1c0d0f683acc",
   "title": "A title",
   "body": "A body",
   "created_at": 164584548,
   "views": []
}
```

^ This document is being created fine in ES based on the data in the topic mentioned above.

However, how do I then add items to the `views` field using messages from another topic. Like so:

`article-view` topic schema:

```
{
   "article_id": "6993e0a6-271b-45ef-8cf5-1c0d0f683acc",
   "user_id": 123456,
   "timestamp: 136389734
}
```

and instead of simply creating a new document on the `article-view` index (which I dont' want to even have). It appends this to the `views` field on the article document with corresponding `_id` equal to `article_id` from the message.

so the end result after one message would be:

```
{
   "_id": "6993e0a6-271b-45ef-8cf5-1c0d0f683acc",
   "uuid": "6993e0a6-271b-45ef-8cf5-1c0d0f683acc",
   "title": "A title",
   "body": "A body",
   "created_at": 164584548,
   "views": [
       {
           "user_id": 123456,
           "timestamp: 136389734
       }
   ]
}
```

Using the ES API it is possible using a script. Like so:

```
{
    "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "params": {
            "newItems": [{
                "timestamp": 136389734,
                "user_id": 123456
            }]
        },
        "source": "ctx._source.views.addAll(params.newItems)"
    }
}
```

I can generate scripts like above dynamically in bulk, and then use the `helpers.bulk` function in the ES Python library to bulk update documents this way.

Is this possible with Kafka Connect / Elasticsearch? I haven't found any documentation on Confluent's website to explain how to do this.

It seems like a fairly standard requirement and an obvious thing people would need to do with Kafka / A sink connector like ES.

Thanks!

Comment: So you have a stream of user pageview events in Kafka, and you want an index in ES with one document per page and embedded within that an array of each user/ts visit? What process/application is this then driving?

Comment: The process then allows us to query the 'page' index directly and get metrics directly without then having to "join" or do subsequent queries to get those metrics.

Comment: I have similar use-case, what i do is send the updated document with it's key. ES "updates" the document because it has the same ket as the previous one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Partial updates are possible with write.method=upsert ([src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61554122/kafka-connect-elasticsearch-when-using-write-method-as-upsert-is-it-possible/61561257#61561257))

---

The Elasticsearch connector doesn't support this. You can update documents in-place but need to send the full document, not a delta for appending which I think it what you're after.

Comment: Thank you for such a quick reply. What would you advise is the best way to achieve this then with Kafka? Or is this simply just not something that can be done...

Comment: @JustinMoser if you want to materialise the state of keys based on data in Kafka I would actually look at Kafka Streams or KSQL. Your application would then query that directly instead.

Comment: Note the [updated answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61561257/6952495): `write.method=upsert`